# How do I obtain the DOCTYPE of an XML document in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala, doctype

Let's suppose we open an XHTML file:

```
val parser = new XhtmlParser(io.Source.fromFile(filename))
val doc = parser.initialize.document
```

It is possible to get the DTD of the document: `doc.dtd`. When I save the XML like in the following line the DOCTYPE is not saved.

```
XML.save("out.xhtml", docRootElem, enc = "UTF-8", xmlDecl = true)
```

I know that `XML.save(...)` method has a parameter `doctype: DocType`, but how do I obtain this from the XML I just opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XML` object has a method with the following signature:

```
def loadXML(source: InputSource, parser: SAXParser): Elem
```

This allows you to supply a `SaxParser`. You could give that `SaxParser` a [`LexicalHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/LexicalHandler.html) which has a method with the following signature:

```
void startDTD(String name, String publicId, String systemId)
```

You could override that. An example:

```
var  r = ("", "", "")                           

val handler = new DefaultHandler2 {
  override def startDTD(name:String, publicId:String, systemId:String) = {
    r = (name, publicId, systemId)
  }
}

val parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
parser.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", handler)

val source = Source fromString """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE wikiarticle SYSTEM "wikiarticle.dtd">
    <wikiarticle>
        <art type="redirect">
            <redirect>#REDIRECT[[page]]</redirect>
        </art>
    </wikiarticle>
"""

XML.loadXML(source, parser)

println(r) // (wikiarticle,null,wikiarticle.dtd)
```

In order to run the example you need a dtd, you can use this:

```
<!ELEMENT wikiarticle (art)>
<!ELEMENT art (redirect, redirect?, article?)>
<!ATTLIST art type CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT redirect (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT article (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: Complicated, but it solves the problem. If nothing simple comes out, I will mark it as the answer.